# Bootstrap "active" tabs don't become active onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Very new to HTML and JS combined with Bootstrap. 
I use the Cyborg-theme and I use the Nav tabs in my HTML-file. 
The problem that I'm getting is that whenever I click on a tab, I want that tab to become the "active" tab. But that doesn't work, instead the only tab that I set to active in the HMTL is the one tab that stays active.

The tabs changes so I get the right information displayed. It's just this little detail that has me very frustrated. Any ideas?

My HTML:

```js
$(".nav li").on("click", function() {
    $("nav li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
```

```html
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#toptracks">Top tracks</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#something">Something</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="about">
                <p>${artist.bio.content}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="toptracks">
                <ul>
                  ${this.tracks.map(track => `<li>${track['name']}</li>`).join('')}
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="something">
              <p>Something in here ...</p>
            </div>
```

Comment: you set the `a` tag to active (manually), and then try to remove/set from the `li` tag. also you miss a period for `.nav`

Comment: you don't ned to write any javascript code for tabs...bootstrap will take care of it...

Comment: why you have added `active` class for all your content `div`? just remove the `active` from other two div's. that will fix the issue.

Comment: When I do this, the information inside the tab disaappears?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `bootstrap` no need for custom `js`
 , it automatically add active to the `li`s

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#toptracks">Top tracks</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#something">Something</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane fade  active in " id="about">
                <p>ghgfhfg</p>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="toptracks">
                <ul>
                  5555
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade " id="something">
              <p>Something in here ...</p>
            </div>
     </div>  
     </div>
```

Comment: When I add this in it seems to interfere with my initial look for the webpage. The Cyborg theme disappears and the information inside the tabs is not showing? :/ no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code inside click event:

```
$("nav li").removeClass("active");
```

to:

```
$(".nav li").removeClass("active");
___^__
```

as in your HTML code, you have a `.nav` class and not the `nav` element and hence the active class is never removed from the initial tab.

Also, add the `active` class to first `li`, not to the link inside it in your HTML

Code:

```js
$(".nav li").on("click", function() {
  $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#toptracks">Top tracks</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#something">Something</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="about">
    <p>${artist.bio.content}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="toptracks">
    <ul>
      ${this.tracks.map(track => `
      <li>${track['name']}</li>`).join('')}
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="something">
    <p>Something in here ...</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: True, but the class wouldn't be removed anyway since he's added `active` to `<a>` :P

Comment: Agreed. `active` class should be added to li, not to the first link